# Hide OpenVPN client's IP

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, ip, openvpn

Is it possible for a OpenVPN server letting clients communicate with one another and they do not know other's IP in VPN?

My VPN server is ubuntu 14.04 32bit

Comment: Are you trying to hide their public IP or the IP their VPN client gets assigned?

Comment: @EEAA , IP their VPN client gets assigned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible with openvpn when you enable the ***client-to-client*** setting, but if you put a proxy in between and direct communication between openvpn clients on the same openvpn server to the proxy then communication between clients will appear to come from that proxy. I think in that case ***client-to-client*** does not (should not?) need to be enabled and you just take care of the appropriate routing yourself. But I never tried that, since whenever I enabled ***client-to-client*** I had no problem with other clients seeing each other's IP.

Of course it will depend on which proxy you use and how you configure it. Squid would only work nice with http traffic, a socks proxy can proxy a lot more.